# Rendering a list of divs from left to right in a row, then rendering rows bottom to top (via CSS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where I have a list of divs with a specific order that need to be rendered in quite a complex way. In simple terms, this is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="box">1 (first in list)</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9 (last in list)</div>
</div>
```

The way in which I want to display the `div`s is in rows of 4 from left to right, with each row stacked from bottom to top, like this:

```
9
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4
```

I have created a fiddle of the result that shows what I'm after: http://jsfiddle.net/mpcjs/ - However, I would like a solution that doesn't require re-ordering of the `div`s in the HTML. Also note that the number of `div`s is variable.

Is this even possible? CSS3/jQuery solutions are welcome!

Comment: >like a solution that doesn't require re-ordering of the divs So I assume you wouldn't want to change the classes of the div's too ? Or is  that a possibility ? If not, am watching this question for some magical replies

Comment: Anything can change (even the HTML), as long as the ordering of the divs is maintained!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the jQuery Plugin [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Replace this (starting at line 287)

```
var position = {
  top: minimumY + this.offset.y
};
```

with

```
var position = (this.options.fromBottom) ? {
  bottom: minimumY + this.offset.y
} : {
  top: minimumY + this.offset.y
};
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fnexE/**

Comment: Nice! Accepted as answer due to better browser compatibility than flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). [Here's a fiddle demonstrating how it would work](http://jsfiddle.net/S94qK/), with the caveat that I have only tested it in Chrome.

```
.flex{
width:400px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-moz-box-pack: start;
-webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
-ms-flex-pack: start;
justify-content: flex-start;
-webkit-align-content: stretch;
-ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
align-content: stretch;}
```

Comment: Just make sure you notice the browser compatibility section. Says it will not work in ANY version of IE or Safari.

Comment: Really nice solution - I accepted the jQuery answer instead simply due to better compatibility. I'll remember this approach for later down the line though!

Comment: I have used the -ms versions of these tags in IE 10 and it does work: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, but I agree that prior to 10 you'd be hosed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a viable solution, *yet*, but with chrome and safari you can use `writing-mode` in CSS3. Check out the [w3-dev section on vertical text](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-writing-modes/#vertical-intro).

```
.row { 
  writing-mode: bt-rl; 
}
.box { 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mpcjs/4/

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how to stack the DIVs from the bottom, but this will reverse them:

*HTML:*

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class='box'>1</div>
        <div class='box'>2</div>
        <div class='box'>3</div>
        <div class='box'>4</div>
        <div class='box'>5</div>
        <div class='box'>6</div>
        <div class='box'>7</div>
        <div class='box'>8</div>
        <div class='box'>9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.box{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:22%;
    margin:1%;
}
```

jQUERY:

```
$('div > .box').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure CSS solution, it would like that:

the basic HTML

```
<div class="container">HOVER ME!
<div class="inner">one</div>
<div class="inner">two</div>
<div class="inner">three</div>
<div class="inner">four</div>
<div class="inner">five</div>
<div class="inner">six</div>
<div class="inner">seven</div>
</div>
```

and we float the inner to the right:

```
.inner {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

That's all !
Well, not all, you still need to hover

```
.container:hover,
.container:hover div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
}
```

Well, that was only to make it a little fun, but the efect is nice, isn't it ?

[test it](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/wh9b8/)